# Adding Averages to a Dataframe

Tags: r

I am working on a baseball related project and I took the averages of the statistic wOBA for each different player from pitch by pitch data. I wanted to add those averages to my original pitch by pitch data frame, but the only problem is that there are multiples of each player ID on the first data frame, so I can't figure out how I am able to attach the averages to each ID. Here's an example of what I'm looking at:

Averages data frame:

```
        batterID  wOBA
  {1}   84621     .321
  {2}   95480     .296
```

Pitch by pitch data frame:

```
        batterID  AB  wOBA average
  {1}   84621     1   (put his average wOBA here)
  {2}   84621     2   (put his average wOBA here)
  {3}   84621     3   (put his average wOBA here)
  {4}   95480     1   (put his average wOBA here)
  {5}   95480     2   (put his average wOBA here)
  {6}   95480     3   (put his average wOBA here)
```

I've tried mutating it, but that didn't work as the data frames have different amounts of columns. What could I do here?

Comment: Have you tried `merge(df1, df2, by = 'batterID')` ?

Comment: I just did, it came back and gave me a data frame with 0 observations

Comment: `merge(..., all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: If you're just learning about merge/join concepts, I suggest you look at these links: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/3358272

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you!

Comment: And I'll take a peek at that, thanks!